# How to add a line to multiple files in directory while adding the users name

Tags: linux, sed, rhel

I am looking for a sed command in linux to add a line to multiple `.bashrc` files in a directory, but want it to adjust for the username.

```
directory: /home/user/
sub directory 1: /fredr/
sub directory 2: /jimw/
file under sub directory: .bashrc
line to add: export KDEVARTMP=/home/user/${user}/
```

But I want the `${user}` to change for each sub directory it goes into, e.g.

```
export KDEVARTMP=/home/user/fredr/
```

and am not looking to replace any lines, only append this line to the bottom the `.bashrc` file of that user.

There are over 100 users in the user directory and want to just apply this updated line to all of them at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for udir in /home/user/*; do
        echo "export KDEVARTMP='$udir'" >> "$udir"/.bashrc
done;
```

Not with `sed` as you asked but will do the job.